# Replace Settings App on LG ls740

Tags: settings

While trying to remove Bloatware on my rooted LG volt LS740, I messed up some apps.  I have done Factory Resets a couple of times and still several apps give the Unfortunately xxx has stopped.  The LG Backup, Browser, Contacts and most importanly to me the Settings app.  The others are get around, but the Settings app is tough to not use.  One error message from Link2SD that I got was that the Odex file is broken and to reinstall app.  HELP, how can I do this?